Loading package from disk in Pycharm
I am trying to load a package in Pycharm that I have on disk.
Everythings works if I do this outside of Pycharm in a venv
pip install -e python/createInput

But using Pycharm's Install Package from Disk

When I click OK, nothing happens.  No error, no acknowledgment.  When I search for my package in the installed packages, it's not there.  And I can't import it anywhere.
Update
I restarted Pycharm and refreshed its packages.  I was able to install my package.  I got a confirmation in the notifications.  And it appears in the package manager

But Pycharm still doesn't recognize it in my code.   Importing in a terminal windows seems to work.  But Pycharm can't find it

But pip knows that it's there

So somehow, I can install it in the package manager, but Pycharm can't seem to find it
Here is a screenshot of my code and the Problems view



It is createInput or createImport?  I suspect you have a typo here.

Ah yes, that one screen shot had a typo.  But Pycharm still can't find it. I corrected the post

OK, but at this point you have shown us screenshots that work, but not one that doesn't.

There's not much to show.  Pycharm shows a red sqiuggly line under any reference to create_input and does not offer to import but only offers to create a class. I'll post a screenshot of the Problems view

You are simply not being careful.  The screenshot with your error imports createInport, not createInput.  Spelling MATTERS.

Yes, that was just my attempt to get together a quick screenshot.  The fact remains that Pycharm is not recognizing the module and is not offering the correct import, whether or not I type it in myself.

Maybe, but you have not shown us that.  It's a little hard to accept what you say when you've had so many typos here.

Line 131 shows that it is an unresolved reference.  Pycharm cannot find it

The screenshot with line 131 highlighted has import createInport instead of import createInput, as I mentioned.

Yes, but it still shows that Pycharm is not suggesting an import.  But I went and corrected the screenshot

NO, THAT'S STILL NOT RIGHT!!   The module name is createInput.  Exactly that.  With a capital, with no underscore.  import createInput.

What I'm trying to say is that I have already tried every possible combination I can think of.  But here's another screenshot

Has pycharm been configured to use your virtual environment?

Yes, I'm using Django and Pycharm handles that stuff automatically.  I've confirmed that it's using the correct environment

Well, Django is irrelevant, but I'd ask that you double-check the Pycharm configuration here:  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html

It turns out that Pycharm only support installing packages with setup.py and does not support packages using pyproject.toml
See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-57566/Support-PEP-660-editable-installs
